# Ionic detect app becomes visible on screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, state

In my ionic app, I would like to detect when the app becomes visible on screen. The use case is, app gets launched but is still in memory (RAM), so none of the `init()` (and similar) functions get triggered.

Is there a way of detecting the app becoming visible on screen again?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The app responds to `resume` listener:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", () => {
    console.log('refocus');
}, false);
```